# Copy the same file into table using COPY command & snowpipe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I coudln't load the samefile into table in snowflake using COPY command/snowpipe.
I am always getting the following result

> **Copy executed with 0 files processed.**

1. I have re-created the table. Truncated the table. But the copy_history doesn't show any data

```
select * from table(information_schema.copy_history(table_name=>'mytable', start_time=> dateadd(hours, -10, current_timestamp())));
```

2. I have used `FORCE = true`  in **COPY Command** and  COPY command didnt load the same file into Table. I have explicitly mentioned file path in COPY COMMAND

```
 FROM
           @STAGE_DEV/myfile/05/28/16/myfile_1.csv

   ) file_format = (
       format_name = STANDARD_CSV_FORMAT Skip_header = 1 FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' NULL_IF = 'NULL'
   ) 
   on_error = continue 
   Force = True;
```

Anyone faced similar issue and what would the process to load the same file again using COPY command or SNOWPIPE ? I dont have option to change file name or put the files in different S3 bucket.

ls@stage shows the following files [ls@stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2g6s.png)

Comment: Are you sure that file exists? ls @STAGE_DEV/myfile/05/28/16/myfile_1.csv

Comment: Are you able to list the files in the stage?

list @my_csv_stage;

Comment: Yes, I can list stage files and i have even tried ALTER PIPE REFRESH and it send 10 files.

Comment: Try removing on_error=continue, as default behavior is to abort statement. Maybe you're getting errors. See if that shows any errors.

Comment: I have changed copy command FROM clause to `@STAGE_DEV/myfile` instead of `@STAGE_DEV/myfile/05/28/16/myfile_1.csv`  and it loaded all 10 files.  Can't a copy command be used to load individual file?   Or Is my statement not correct to load a speciifc file.  The File gets loaded into S3 in 10 Parts.

Answer (score 0):

I have reloaded files to S3 bucket and it's working. Thank you guys for all the responses. –